# Laravel keep an array across requests

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to keep an array across requests in Laravel? I found this note in the Laravel documentation.

> array - sessions will be stored in a simple PHP array and will not be persisted across requests.

Even if I try to keep my array in a normal session variable

```
$_SESSION['data'] = $myDate;
```

I will lose my session array across page request. I can not regenerate my array across page request because it takes over 20 sec to get the data.

Comment: What are you trying to pass from request to request? Is it on the same domain? Does it concern logged in users only? Session and Cookies seems viable options. Have you tried using [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session) Classes for those?

Comment: I tried Session::put('data' , $myData) but this session is deleted across page request since it is an array. I am trying to keep airfare results (~10mb data) from a user research across pages.

Comment: That note you found is only true when you use array as the session driver. If you use another driver such as a file, it'll be persisted across requests. Also keep in mind, that if you want to use PHP native session, you'll need to call `session_start()` in each request.

Comment: In app/config/session.php driver is set to : driver => 'file'

I totaly forgot about session_start()...